# Count Remaining Days per Fiscal Month

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Based on this Post I am building a fiscal calendar:

The following Dax generates a DAX Calendar:

```
Calendar = 
VAR BaseCalendar =
    CALENDAR ( DATE ( 2016; 1; 1 ); DATE ( 2025; 12; 31 ) )
RETURN
    GENERATE (
        BaseCalendar;
        VAR BaseDate = [Date]
        VAR Year =
            YEAR ( BaseDate )
        VAR MonthNumber =
            MONTH ( BaseDate )
        VAR WeekNumber =
            WEEKNUM ( BaseDate )
        VAR FWeek =
            WEEKNUM ( BaseDate; 21 )
        RETURN
            ROW (
                "Day"; BaseDate;
                "Year"; Year;
                "Month Number"; MonthNumber;
                "Month"; FORMAT ( BaseDate; "mmmm" );
                "Year Month"; FORMAT ( BaseDate; "yyyy-mm" );
                "Day of Week"; FORMAT ( BaseDate; "dddd" );
                "Day of Week Short"; FORMAT ( BaseDate; "ddd" );
                "Week"; WeekNumber;
                "Year-Week"; Year & "-" & WeekNumber;
                "Fiscal Week"; FWeek;
                "Fiscal Month Short"; SWITCH (
                    TRUE ();
                    FWeek IN { 1; 2; 3; 4 }; "Jan";
                    FWeek IN { 5; 6; 7; 8 }; "Feb";
                    FWeek IN { 9; 10; 11; 12; 13 }; "Mar";
                    FWeek IN { 14; 15; 16; 17 }; "Apr";
                    FWeek IN { 18; 19; 20; 21 }; "May";
                    FWeek IN { 22; 23; 24; 25; 26 }; "Jun";
                    FWeek IN { 27; 28; 29; 30 }; "Jul";
                    FWeek IN { 31; 32; 33; 34 }; "Aug";
                    FWeek IN { 35; 36; 37; 38; 39 }; "Sep";
                    FWeek IN { 40; 41; 42; 43 }; "Oct";
                    FWeek IN { 44; 45; 46; 47 }; "Nov";
                    FWeek IN { 48; 49; 50; 51; 52; 53 }; "Dec"
            )
    )
```

Now I need a column that shows me remaining days for the respective fiscal month for every date.
I would suggest I need a first column, that accumulates the working days per month.
Then I need a second column that subtract this value from the total sum for the corresponding month.

How would you add build that into the calendar in the same approach provided above?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you define as a working day. I'm presuming it is Mon-Fri
You need a new column added to your above DAX to return a 1 or 0

```
IsWeekDay = SWITCH(TRUE(), WEEKDAY(Calendar[Date], 2) <= 5, 1, 0)
```

So it will return 1 for Mon-Fri, 0 for anything else.
Next add a column for your month start date, I'm using the Calendar Month in this example:

```
MonthStart = STARTOFMONTH(Calendar[Date])
```

For a date of 04/04/2020, it will return a date of 01/04/2020

The next new column should sum up the working days using EARILER

```
Working Days = 
CALCULATE ( SUM('Calendar'[IsWeekDay]),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Calendar' ),
        'Calendar'[Date] >= EARLIER ( 'Calendar'[Date] )
            &&  EARLIER('Calendar'[MonthStart]) = STARTOFMONTH('Calendar'[Date])
    )
)
```

You'll have to adjust it for your Fiscal Month Start Date

[image: Power BI Example Working Days]

Comment: Hey Jonee! Many thanks for your approach! My approach for the calendar table is based on GENERATE/RETURN/ROW. Here I can't add columns like you are showing. And since I have a fiscal calendar a function like "MonthStart = STARTOFMONTH(Calendar[Date])" will not work. Our start and end dates are different to the dates with a gregorian calendar.